# F# Count how Many times a substring Contains within a string

Tags: string, count, f#, contains

How could one count how many times a substring exists within a string?

I mean if you have a String "`one, two, three, one, one, two"` how could you make it count "one" being present 3 times?

I thought `String.Contains` would be able to do the job but that only checks if the substring is present at all. `String.forall` is for chars and therefofre niether an option.

So i am really at a complete halt here. Can some enligten me?

Comment: I would select an answer but based on your comments there seems to be some dispute about which is the best solution. So im in a bit of a dilema here. I really appreciate all of your solutions though. Given me so much to think about.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Regex.Escape` to turn the string you're searching for into a regex, then use regex functions:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let countMatches wordToMatch (input : string) =
    Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape wordToMatch).Count
```

Test:

```
countMatches "one" "one, two, three, one, one, two"
// Output: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation that walks through the string, using `String.IndexOf` to skip through to the next occurrence of the substring, and counts up how many times it succeeds.

```
let substringCount (needle : string) (haystack : string) =
    let rec loop count (index : int) =
        if index >= String.length haystack then count
        else
            match haystack.IndexOf(needle, index) with
            | -1 -> count
            | idx -> loop (count + 1) (idx + 1)
    if String.length needle = 0 then 0 else loop 0 0
```

Bear in mind, this counts overlapping occurrences, e.g., `subtringCount "aa" "aaaa" = 3`.  If you want non-overlapping, simply replace `idx + 1` with `idx + String.length needle`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence of tails of the string to search in, that is, all substring slices anchored at its end. Then you can use `forall` functionality to determine the number of matches against the beginning of each of them. It's just golfier than `(fun s -> s.StartsWith needle)`.

```
let count needle haystack =
    [ for i in 0..String.length haystack - 1 -> haystack.[i..] ]
    |> Seq.filter (Seq.forall2 (=) needle)
    |> Seq.length

count "aba" "abacababac"
// val it : int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

a fellow student of mine came up with the so far simpelst solutions i have seen.

```
let countNeedle (haystack :string) (needle : string) =
      match needle with
      | "" -> 0
      | _ -> (haystack.Length - haystack.Replace(needle, "").Length) / needle.Length
```

Comment: Beware that this can't catch the overlapping case, and requires the allocation of a new string - it's unlikely to be a problem, but is something to consider.

Comment: The simplest and fastest one is the regex. This case is the slowest of the three because it processes all characters, generates a temporary string (which the others don't) and then perfoms length calculations.

Comment: @Panagiotis The regex one is definitely the shortest, but not the fastest - using the full regex engine is rarely going to be as fast as a simpler algorithm.  In my quick tests, the `String.IndexOf` method is twice as fast on many loops of small inputs, and is 10x faster when searching long strings.

Comment: @JakeLishman 1) only if your method *doesn't* generate any temporary strings. In this case only, this is possible. String splitting may appear fast and simple too, but the number of temporary strings and garbage collection cost result in more than 10x slower execution.

Comment: @JakeLishman 2) [IndexOf](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,85e3ffb17534f9ef) is a wrapper over an OS function. That's almost cheating - at that level you can use a lot of optimizations, even use SIMD operations to compare multiple bytes in one operation

Comment: @JakeLishman 3) it seems this is a [Rosetta problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring) with far too many bad implementations. This answer seems to be the F# implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
// This approach assumes the data is comma-delimited.
let data = "one, two, three, one, one, two"
let dataArray = data.Split([|','|]) |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Trim())
let countSubstrings searchTerm = dataArray |> Array.filter (fun x -> x = searchTerm) |> Array.length
let countOnes = countSubstrings "one"

let data' = "onetwothreeoneonetwoababa"

// This recursive approach makes no assumptions about a delimiter,
// and it will count overlapping occurrences (e.g., "aba" twice in "ababa").
// This is similar to Jake Lishman's answer.
let rec countSubstringFromI s i what = 
    let len = String.length what
    if i + len - 1 >= String.length s then 0
    else (if s.Substring(i, len) = what then 1 else 0) + countSubstringFromI s (i + 1) what

let countSubStrings' = countSubstringFromI data' 0 "one"
```